# Meaning ans translation of 「取り組み」

Tags: translation

The word 「取り【とり】組み【くみ】」is generally translated as "efforts", but when I want to translate some certain sentence, this English word does't fit well, I think.

For example:

> 社員満足度【しゃいんまんぞくど】を向上【こうじょう】するための**取り【とり】組み【くみ】**
>   = ***Efforts*** to improve employee satisfaction

or

> 安全対策【あんぜんたいさく】の**取り【とり】組み【くみ】** とその強化【きょうか】 = ***Efforts*** for safety measures and it's reinforcement

In which situations is the word 「取り【とり】組み【くみ】」usually used and how we should better translate it?

Comment: I found the word initiative on jisho.org.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I found this word too, but I have no idea how it could fit the certain sentences... So it would have any logic.

Comment: Contributions may be a consideration for use

Answer (score 1):

I have found various words such as initiatives which could fit depending on the entire context. If not, how about **Commitment**?

E.g Commitment to improving employee satisfaction

Comment: Thank you, also good alternative I think. But I still can hear "angles" in the translation... I feel like something is missing...